# Want to show data from two different sql tables in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i show data from two tables in my sql database in the view...?

Please help.

1. table is Profile
2. table is Company

I want two different tables in my view to show these data from database.!

I have searched in the internet but i couldn't find anything to solve my problem. Please help.

I have no problem with one table in my view.

```
public ActionResult Profiler()
{
    using (var dc = new Models.DataDataContext()) // Opretter objekt af model(Databasen)
    {
        return View(dc.Profils.OrderByDescending(a => a.Nu).ToList()); // Returner en liste med tabellets indhold
    }
}
```

This give me a table with data from my database in my view. But i want my second table too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to achieve is termed a "View Model" because the model you are sending to your views is different that the model in your database. Often times you will find that you may need to create a view for the UI that doesn't exactly match the database.

jgauffin shows a "DetailsModel" which combines two database entities. This is as simple as creating a class and giving it two properties, CompanyName and Username. What his code is missing is the code for the "DetailsModel" class. Instead of passing two entities you create a single entity that has all of the properties you need.

Surjit also has a method to do such without the use of a seperate View Model class by using a Tuple.

You will need to modify your view to accept either the Tuple or your new View Model.

Comment: This is still not enough to solve my problem. I cant understand these methods. Can you give me a better example?

Comment: Murat are you familiar with creating a class? A ViewModel is nothing more than creating a class with properties for all of the different tables you would like to pass to the view. A quick Google search returned the following video from ASP.NET http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-implement-view-models-to-manage-data-for-aspnet-mvc-views

Answer (score 1):

Load information from both tables and create a flattened view model which the relavant information from both tables:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var profile = _profileRepos.Get(id);
    var company = _companyRepos.Get(profile.CompanyId);
    var model = new DetailsModel {
        CompanyName = company.Name,
        UserName = profile.FullName
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this with a little more details.

I want to show these data in my Index.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question first. What kind of data layer do you use? What have you tried so far?